# Get all possible string sequences where each element comes from different set in R

Tags: string, r, combinations, permutation, diacritics

Assume I have 4 vectors of `character` elements:

```
s1 <- c("o", "ó")
s2 <- c("c", "ć")
s3 <- c("o", "ó")
s4 <- c("z", "ź", "ż")
```

I want to build 4-element vectors that are **all possible combinations** of elements from `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4` in a way that in one of a result vectors 1-st, -2nd, 3-rd and 4-th element comes from `s1`, `s2`, `s3`, `s4`, respectively.

For example, I would like to get the following result vectors:

```
[1] "o", "c", "o", "z"
[1] "ó", "c", "o", "z"
[1] "o", "ć", "o", "z"

...
```

[*My general goal of it is to produce all possible words from a given word in my native, assuming the given word have some diacritic marks ommited. I firstly extract all character candidates for being a diacritic mark and then want to inject them or their diacritic  equivalents.*]

Comment: How about `?expand.grid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not super elegant but using the definitions for `s1`-`s4` above, here is a quick for loop of for loops that will print the vectors you requested.

```
for(a in s1){
  for(b in s2){
    for(c in s3){
      for(d in s4){
        print(c(a,b,c,d))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[1] "o" "c" "o" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "o" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "o" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "ó" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "ó" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "ó" "z"
[1] "o" "c" "o" "z" 
[...]
```

As shadow said above, `expand.grid()` is a much more elegant solution:

`expand.grid(list(s1,s2,s3,s4))`

Output:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4
1     o    c    o    z
2     ó    c    o    z
3     o    c    o    z
4     ó    c    o    z
5     o    c    ó    z
6     ó    c    ó    z
7     o    c    ó    z
8     ó    c    ó    z
[...]
```

Comment: @shadow `?expand.grid` is probably a much better answer

Answer (score 1):

You may also check `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res <- CJ(s1=s1,s2=s2,s3=s3,s4=s4) #order the result by columns
```

Checking with results obtained from `expand.grid`

```
res2 <- expand.grid(s1=s1,s2=s2,s3=s3,s4=s4,stringsAsFactors=F)
res2New <- res2[with(res2, order(s1,s2,s3,s4)),]
all.equal(res2New, as.data.frame(res),check.attributes=F)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I benchmarked it and `expand.grid` is much faster (with the elements of size similar to these from my post example).

Comment: `user3793180`. I tried system.time(expand.grid(1:1000,1:10000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.418   0.064   0.483 
> system.time(CJ(1:1000,1:10000))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.015   0.021   0.036.

Comment: I do believe data.table beats exmpand.grid when we talk aboult larger data being touched. While I tested `system.time(res <- CJ(s1=s1,s2=s2,s3=s3,s4=s4))` and 
`system.time(res2 <- expand.grid(s1=s1,s2=s2,s3=s3,s4=s4,stringsAsFactors=F))`, I got `user  system elapsed 0.03    0.00    0.03 ` and `user  system elapsed 0.01    0.00    0.01`, respectively :)