# Expand grid R function functionality in c++

Tags: c++, r

Some time ago I asked for solution to my problem in `R` and [expand grid was a perfect solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506602/get-all-possible-string-sequences-where-each-element-comes-from-different-set-in) to it. Is there any `c++` equivalent for that function (working on char arrays)?

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: Why does this have to be a new question? What's unresolved from your previous question? What have you tried since you got the previous answer, and where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried google it but cannot find an answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure c++ implementation or are you going to use the code with R, e.g. can you use the R-library or Rcpp?

Comment: @user3793180 In that case https://github.com/DavisDaddy/DirksRcppStuff/blob/master/Rcpp.org#function might help.